# how do I write an if/else statement in Racket?

Tags: racket

How do i write an if else statement in this code?

I am new to AI and we are learning about if/else statements. I am unsure about how to write the else statement. I continuously get errors.

```
(define (nextmove location status)
        (if (eq? status 'dirty) 'suck 'no\idea))
```

SO here ^^^ i have to write an if/else statement to print out the following

```
> (nextmove 'A 'dirty)
'suck
> (nextmove 'B 'clean)
'left
```

However, it is printing out

```
<(nextmove 'B 'clean)
'noidea
```

Comment: It's returning `'noidea` because that's what you wrote in the else-part of your `if`. If you want it to return `'left`, replace `'noidea` with `'left`.

Comment: Develop a Racket function to simulate the basic (reflex) vacuum cleaner agent as described in chapter 2 of your book.  Your function is called nextmove, and takes as input the current square ('A or 'B) and whether or not the square is dirty ('dirty or 'clean).  It then returns the move to make, either 'right, 'left, or 'suck.  For example:
> (nextmove 'A 'dirty)
'suck
> (nextmove 'B 'clean)
'left

Comment: Im unsure how to write an "else" statement to print out 'left or 'right if a space is clean

Comment: No code in your question prints anything. It returns values and it is printed by the REPL. To explicitly print something you need to use `(display "suck")`. Have you considered replacing the symbol `'no\idea` with `'left` and what affect that would have?

Answer (score 1):

```
#lang racket

(define (nextmove location status)
        (cond
          [(eq? status 'dirty) 'suck]
          [(eq? status 'clean) 'left]
          [else 'noidea]))
```

[Conditionals: if, cond, and, and or](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html)